# Can I save the value of a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one text box and have written "ABC" in the text box, but I want to obtain the text using jQuery

```
<input type=text value="ABC">
```

But when I use jQuery's `.html()` it returns null

Comment: `.val()` you want to use

Comment: Input tags have no content as they are self closing. Thus `text()` and `html()` will return nothing.

Comment: @Enijar Quotes are optional

Comment: is this really hard to research online?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Fx9Ap/)**</kbd>

```
<input type="text">

<span></span>
```

---

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('span').text($(this).val());
});
```

or

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('span').html($(this).val());
});
```